align html div blocks horizontally
I am designing a website. Currently, I am trying to align several div blocks in rows. My code look as follows


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header styles */
.header {
  background-color: #eee8e8;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.header-top {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo a {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #007bff;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #0056b3;
}

/*category section*/
.main-content h3 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
}

.category-select a {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  padding: 15px 0px 0px 10em;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #27285f;
}

.category-title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10em;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Choose category</title>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="header-top">        
        <nav class="nav-links">
          <a href="/sign-up" class="nav-link">Sign Up</a>
          <a href="/log-in" class="nav-link">Log In</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="main-content">
      <h3>please choose a category</h3>
      <div class="group-select">
        <div class="category-select">
          <a href="#">Housing</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Housing Available</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Housing Wanted</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Other</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group-select">
        <div class="category-select">
          <a href="#">For Sale</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Appliance </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Clothes </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Electronics </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Free </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> General </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Garage Sale </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Household </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Transportation </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Wanted </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Other </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group-select">
        <div class="category-select">
          <a href="#">Jobs</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#"> Admin Office </a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Contractor</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Customer Service</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Driver</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Food Restaurant</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">General Labor</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Job Seeking</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Manufacturing</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Sales</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Software IT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="category-title">
          <a href="#">Other</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



The categories are not aligned line by line horizontally as the picture shows:

I tried to change add margin and set it to auto in category title class,but it does not work.Is it something wrong with the inline-block property?

paste all the link (a tags)

I cannot reproduce the issue you describe with the code provided. Please post enough code in the form of a [repro] that shows this issue.

I have edited the code, it should reproduce the result as the picture shows

Inline blocks width is based on content length, unless you give it a fixed width. Any padding is added to the content, so you end up with blocks of varying widths. This is why they are not aligning like you want. Investigate flexbox or CSS Grid, both of which will require some adjustments to your HTML

I used the grid, and changed the html accordingly, it worked great! Thanks for the advice.

.category-title {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 10px 0px 10em;
  width: 0px;
}


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
